# C# - Magento: get all products

Tags: c#, visual-studio, magento, soap

Hi I need all product collection information in c# code of all products. Currently there are 3  products i have added, i am using Magento soap api v1 and visual studio 2015.

i have tried

```
var allprod = mservice.catalogProductAttributeList(mlogin, 1);
```

where mlogin is session 1 is setid

Comment: What is your question? What is your problem with the code you have? You should read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

catalogProductEntity[] resultArray = mservice.catalogProductList(mlogin, myfilter, null);

foreach (var prodid in resultArray)
{
catalogProductReturnEntity ResultAllProducts = mservice.catalogProductInfo(mlogin, prodid.product_id, null, null, null);

}

In ResultAllProducts we can get all items one by one.

like  ResultAllProducts.name,ResultAllProducts.price,ResultAllProducts.product_id etc;